# Folder Paths in Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

My application needs to move the files from input folder to error folder , after validation and im using -->Files.move in java and it works in my machine ,and want to achieve the same in Pivotal Cloud ,since couldnt use the same as its not working in cloud .Do i need to tweak the below or any other alternatives out there ?Thanks in advance !!

```
            String inputFolder="\\home\\**\\**\\***\\input_working";
            String errorFolder = "\\home\\**\\**\\***\\input_errors";

            for (String inputTextFile : errorfiles) {
                String msg = this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "- Input file has errors, Moving it to Error Directory ..."+inputFolder+inputTextFile+" To "+errorFolder+ inputTextFile;
                LOGGER.info(REPORT_MARKER,LOG_HVML_TEMPLATE_TWO,msg,2);
                Files.move(Paths.get(inputFolder + "\\"+ inputTextFile), Paths.get(errorFolder + "\\"+ inputTextFile));
            }
```

Comment: Using filesystems is a anti-pattern for Cloud Native apps. The reason is disk assigned to the container is meant to ephemeral (meaning, will be available only for the lifetime of the container). 

If you do need some storage, look at an s3 storage and add it as a CUPS resource to your cloud environment and bind to your apps.

Answer (score 0):

On a cloud foundry instance you can use NFS Volume Services. you can create a service and bind it to the application, then you can read and write to the file system path.

You can follow [this documentation](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-11/devguide/services/using-vol-services.html) for the exact steps